# Flickering horizontal lines in full screen

Tags: display, fullscreen

Tried disabling either Intel HD Graphics or Nvidia card -- same result, so it seems to be a monitor problem, not a graphics card problem:

[image: image not full screen: no bug]

[image: same image in full screen: flickering horizontal lines]

Apparently related to slight color changes on the vertical line on the extreme left side of the screen.

Any idea? Thanks.

EDIT: the problem is predictable, the lines follow the mouse cursor when it spills on the edge of the screen, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQSQQ.jpg).

Comment: Have you tried a different cable or connection methods (HDMI or DisplayPort, e.g.)?

Comment: @P Fitz: it's a laptop. When I connect it to an external monitor through HDMI, the problem does NOT occur on the external monitor. Looks like the monitor itself or the internal cable between laptop and monitor.

Comment: I gotcha now. Do you see any sort of change when you adjust the laptop lid?
Based on your edit, it isn't necessarily triggered by going from windowed to full screen, just whether or not there's color variation on the left-most edge of the screen. Do I have that right?

Comment: @P Fitz: no change at all when I adjust the lid, so less likely to be bad contacts on the internal DVI cable I guess. Yes you're correct in that it's not directly related to fullscreen, sometimes it happens with various windows on screen: the problem is predictable, certain pixel pixel configurations on the screen create it consistently (in some cases related to left-most edge pixels content, but there may be other triggers), it's just that the kind of pixels configuration which creates the problem is more likely to happen in full screen.

Comment: @P Fitz: My guess: it seems to be related to some kind of optimization algorithms of the screen controller, which, in some pixels configurations, somehow lose synchronization with the screen's VSync, so that some vertical lines are de-synced and horizontally shifted as a result.

Comment: I assume you've already tried updating the drivers? Does it happen when set to lower resolutions?

Comment: @P Fitz: Yes tried updating all drivers (Intel HD graphics and Nvidia), no change. Just tried with different resolutions: virtually identical problem in 1366x768 (native resolution is 1920x1080). However in 1400x1050, the aspect ratio is different so it's like there are big black bars on the left and right sides of the screen, and no bug -- no flickering lines. This seems to confirm that it's a purely screen problem, apparently related to the pixel content on the edges of the screen, maybe left edge.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your graphic properties in device manager and change the DPI settings to suit you either higher or lower if this doesn't work it means it's either the cable or if you are using a splitter it might be the problem .